# React Global Styles

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am building a react project and having some issues with scss variables.

Firstly I am **NOT** using css modules so please don't suggest that as a solution.

Essentially I am including styles in the component folder, but I also have global shared styles that exist in an app folder called `styles.scss` this includes imports for the scss variables, mixins etc that i'd like to use in the component files. I'm having issues sharing the variables, I tried importing the styles into navigation.js is that the correct way to do it? I'd love some advice.

The folder structure is like this (it has to be this way as it is an existing project that I cannot change so please no suggestions for restructuring)

```
> components
   > button
   > navigation
     > navigation.scss
     > navigation.js
   > carousel
> app
   > scss
      > settings
         > mixin.scss
         > variables.scss
   > index.js
   > styles.scss
```

Styles.scss

```
 @import '/scss/settings/variables';
 @import '/scss/settings/mixins';
```

Variables.scss

```
 $black: #000;
 $white: #fff;
 $fontsize: 16px;
```

navigation.scss

```
@import '../../app/scss/settings/variables';

.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    background: $black;
    color: $white;
 }
```

*Note: i'm using webpack to bundle my scss.*

Comment: Are you add examples of what your styles.scss and maybe an example of how you're trying to use the variables in your navigation.scss?

Comment: @ZacBraddy I have updated as requested, is that the correct idea or are you meant to do it another way?

Comment: That relative path from navigation doesn't lead to the variables file you are going one directory too high. I assume this is a typo and not the case in your actual code?

Comment: @ZacBraddy yes sorry that is a typo, it's not the case in the actual code.

Comment: If that's the case I can't see a good reason why this wouldn't work, I can understand why you're confused now :) I'm at work right now but when I get home I'll try and mock up a little environment and try it myself and let you know what I find.